# React components rendering with wrong props when changing filter

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have a page in a react app that uses a radio form to filter different objects of data that are being passed to the page.

The problem I am encountering, is that when I change the filter, (click on a different option on the radio form), only some of the data in the resulting list changes. A simple example of what happens is as follows:

Option one is selected with all the old data

[image]

Option two is selected, but only some of the new data comes through
[image]

First, I use an axios request to get an array of objects that will be used for the data:

```
componentDidMount() {
        axios.get("xxxxxxxxx")
            .then(result => {
                this.setState({
                    data: result.data
                });
            });
```

Then, I create an array that filters the data from axios by an attribute based on which radio option is selected in the form:

```
let filteredData = [];

filteredData = this.state.data.filter(thisData => thisData.attribute === "attribute1");
```

Finally, I map all of the filtered data in the render function:

```
filteredData.map(filteredItem => ( <MyComponent key={i++} itemInfo={filteredItem.info} /> ))
```

In the definition of MyComponent, I use props to access the filtered item's info and put it into the table like this:

```
<td>{this.props.itemInfo.thisDataPoint}</td>
```

I'd love to hear if anybody has any idea why *some* of the components data updates when the filter changes, but not all of it. It seems weird to me that some data changes but some does not.

I have tried converting the props into state so that the component re-renders on the change but that did not work.

Thanks again for any help I get :)

Comment: if you console.log(filteredData), will you see the expected data values on change selected radio button?

Comment: @buzatto yep console.log-ing the data being retrieved and console.log-ing the filteredData shows correct data. It seems to be strictly the ui elements not changing, even though the values underneath should be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

given that `filteredData` is correct, and based on your code the issue must be on `key={i++}`. using some kind of implementation index can often lead to rendering problems, react will have trouble to distinguish the components since it uses the key to track them.

you should provide some unique identifier to each component as key like `key={filteredItem.id}`. if you don't have it, you can generate it with some library like [uuid](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid).

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much. Your solution makes sense and works :)